# Wrap Text like the latest Safari does with white-space: pre

Tags: html, css, text, safari, textarea

Safari does a wonderful job wrapping text when `white-space: pre;` is applied to `<div>`s or `<textarea>`s, like below.

```
<textarea style="width:300px; white-space:pre; word-wrap:break-word;"> text. dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</textarea>
```

When a word reaches the `max-width` of the textarea the entire word isn't moved down a line the way it is if you just use `word-wrap: break-word;`. Instead, it splits the word at the `max-width` and continues from the lower left newline. I'd like to be able to replicate this in all the major browsers, but I'd be satisfied with just Firefox and IE if it's too troublesome.

Any ideas/advice on how to achieve this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what safari does differently?

Comment: http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/2012/firefoxva.png http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/7020/safarik.png

Comment: @Smith the links are dead

Answer (score 2):

Use [`overflow-wrap` or `word-wrap`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#overflow-wrap). They are synonyms, but from my experience, `word-wrap` works in most browsers:

```
textarea {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

This will insert hard breaks.

Comment: Here is more precision about differences between `word-wrap` and `overflow-wrap`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17259958/2477545

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me

```
white-space: normal;
word-break: break-word;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.