# word-wrap: break-word not working on lists in Safari 10.1

Tags: html, css, safari, word-wrap

Here's my very specific scenario: word-wrap: break word is not working on lists in Safari 10.1 if the first line overflows. Every other line will break properly. The first line will break if with hyphens: auto.

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/3smrv3tk/

```
<ol class="test"><li>wrapwraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaap</li></ol>
```

screenshot:
[word-wrap: break-word in Safari 10.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujSIM.png)

The worst-case scenario is that I use -webkit-hyphens: auto, but hopefully someone has a more disguised solution!

Answer (score 3):

word-break: break-all;

```html
<div style="width: 100px;border: 1px solid red">
 <ol class="test"><li>wrapwraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaap</li></ol>
</div>

<br><br><br> 
it's Working Fine
<br><br>
<div style="width: 100px;border: 1px solid red">
 <ol class="test"><li style="word-break: break-all;">wrapwraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaap</li></ol>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using `overflow-wrap` instead of `word-wrap`

[Difference between overflow-wrap and word-break?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259916/difference-between-overflow-wrap-and-word-break#17259958)

Comment: No dice, first line still not wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

You can add style `hyphens:auto;` to your li elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

word-wrap: anywhere;
white-space: pre-wrap;

Comment: According to the documentation, the word-wrap: anywhere does not exist https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.php