# HTML DOM Style overflow-wrap

Tags: jquery, css

I have been using "overflow-wrap: break-word;" in a CSS class and the element having that class.

Long story but I want to hard code the style into the element, however there doesn't seem to be a syntax for overflow-wrap via element.style....

Answer (score 0):

You can apply css to an object using jQuery like this:

```
$('#element').css('overflow-wrap', 'break-word');
```

Comment: I know, but as I am building the element up I was hoping to add it via the style method with the others.  Is it possible?

Comment: Have you looked into the css styles wordWrap and wordBreak?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259916/difference-between-overflow-wrap-and-word-break

Comment: Do you mean an inline style on the element itself, or adding a style block to the head of the page (if it's the former, OP's solution does exactly that, if it's the latter you may want to clarify in your question).

Answer (score 0):

If you are dynamically adding elements then I would suggest you write this as a function that is called whenever a new element is added, probably using an event listener, that you can pass your updated style values to as parameters. Something like:

```
updateDOMStyle('<style>','<value>');
```