# Word-wrap doesn't respect parent's width for long non-break text

Tags: html, css, overflow, word-wrap, word-break

```css
.container {
  /* 
     Container's width can be dynamically resized. 
     I put width = 300px in the example to demonstrate a case 
     where container's width couldn't hold second msg 
  */
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: blue;
}

.parent{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
  padding:1em;
  background-color:red;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.name{
  background-color:mistyrose;
  width: 70px;
  padding: 1em;
}
.msg{
  background-color:powderblue;
  max-width: 30vw;
  padding:.5em;
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
 <div class="parent">
    <div class="name">
      David
    </div>
    <div class="msg">
    How are you? How are you? How are you? How are you? How are you? How are you? How are you? How are you? How are you? How are you? How are you? How are you? How are you? 

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="name">
      Hannah
    </div>
    <div class="msg">
    somethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomething

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ideally , I want each `msg` to have max-width of `30vw`, but at the same time respect parent's width. The **first** row behaves correctly, but the **second** row doesn't. If parent's width is resized to some value smaller than 30vw, the **second** msg will overflow.

I want something like `max-width = min(30vw, parent's width)`

**NOTE**: Container's width can be dynamically resized. I put width = 300px in the example to demonstrate a case where container cannot hold the second msg which somehow has width = it's max-width = 30vw.

**You can also see the example at** http://jsfiddle.net/vbj10x4k/231/

Comment: simply because there is no rule saying this .. the max-width is related to viewport unit

Comment: I would use `word-break:break-word;` instead - that should work better

Comment: @TemaniAfif but why does the first message adjust to its parent's width? they have same className

Comment: @Pete Thanks. However `word-break:break-word;` is not supported in Firefox :'(

Comment: Of course it is.

Comment: @PhucNguyen just use both - then it will work: http://jsfiddle.net/vbj10x4k/238/

Comment: because the first you have a logical line break to fit the container ...unlike the second one where there is no line break

Comment: @Pete Thanks. But in your example you already modified the `max-width` of `msg`. I want to set it to `30vw`, but still fit in the container if container's width is smaller than 30vw (like first row)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply set `max-width:100%` to `.parent` so this one respect the width of `.container` then rely on flex and your element will shrink by default. Also don't forget `min-width:0` on the element itself [to enable the element to shrink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-dont-flex-items-shrink-past-content-size).

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: blue;
}

.parent{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
  padding:1em;
  background-color:red;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  max-width:100%; /*Added this */
}
.name{
  background-color:mistyrose;
  width: 70px;
  padding: 1em;
}
.msg{
  background-color:powderblue;
  max-width:30vw;
  min-width:0; /*addedd this*/
  padding:.5em;
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
 <div class="parent">
    <div class="name">
      David
    </div>
    <div class="msg">
    How are you? How are you? How are you? How are you? How are you? How are you? How are you? How are you? How are you? How are you? How are you? How are you? How are you? 

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="name">
      Hannah
    </div>
    <div class="msg">
    somethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomething

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated the post to add note. I mean the container's width can be dynamically resized. So ideally I don't want to set fixed value to children's max-width :D

Comment: @PhucNguyen but at least did you understand why the issu ? ... remove the max-width and you will see how the first one and second behave

Comment: no I don't understand. both `msg`s have the same class. first msg also has `max-width = 30vw`, but it still fits in the container, while the second one doesn't fit

Comment: @PhucNguyen but remove the max-width and see what is happeing ... you will see that the first one is already fitting and the second one is overflowing TOO much ... so max-width simply reduced this second overflow

Comment: Perfect solution! Work on all browsers. I should have saved myself 1 day if I asked earlier.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need to support IE11 or safari, a simple solution would be to switch your `word-wrap:break-word;` with
`word-wrap: anywhere` ([working example](http://jsfiddle.net/xs2dbtL8/))

If you need to support safari (but still not IE11), then instead replace `word-wrap:break-word;` with `word-break: break-word`. Note that `word-break: break-word` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) in favour of `word-wrap: anywhere`.

I would also recommend switching `word-wrap` for its more commonly used alias: `overflow-wrap`. It will be more effective when used in a search term.

Also see: [Difference between overflow-wrap and word-break?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259916/difference-between-overflow-wrap-and-word-break)

Answer (score 0):

Just add :

```
word-break: break-all;
```

in
    .msg

Comment: this will break anywhere. I want to preserve the whole word.