# Do `overflow-wrap: break-word` and `word-break: break-word` ever behave differently?

Tags: html, css, break

**My question:**

Is there any difference between `overflow-wrap: break-word` and `word-break: break-word`?

**Non-duplicates:**

Here are some existing questions that may appear to be duplicates at first sight but aren't.

- [What is the difference between "word-break: break-all" versus "word-wrap: break-word" in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795109/what-is-the-difference-between-word-break-break-all-versus-word-wrap-break) (That question is about `word-break: break-all` but my question here is about `word-break: break-word`)
- [Difference between overflow-wrap and word-break?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259916/difference-between-overflow-wrap-and-word-break) (That question asks about `overflow-wrap` and `word-break` attributes but my question here is about the `break-word` value for this attributes in particular. Also, that question is mysteriously marked as a duplicate of the previous question even though it is unrelated.)

**Code:**

I wrote this code snippet that appears to show that both `overflow-wrap: break-word` and `word-break: break-word` behave the same way. But I don't know for sure if I have accounted for all cases. Maybe there is a case in which they behave differently?

```css
.ow {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.wb {
  word-break: break-word;
  background: lightblue;
}

div {
  width: 5em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="ow">
Honorificabilitudinitatibus califragilisticexpialidocious Taumatawhakatangihangakoauauotamateaturipukakapikimaungahoronukupokaiwhenuakitanatahu
</div>

<div class="wb">
Honorificabilitudinitatibus califragilisticexpialidocious Taumatawhakatangihangakoauauotamateaturipukakapikimaungahoronukupokaiwhenuakitanatahu
</div>

<div class="ow">
Most words are short and don't need to break. But Antidisestablishmentarianism is long.
</div>

<div class="wb">
Most words are short and don't need to break. But Antidisestablishmentarianism is long.
</div>
```

**Browser support:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap#Browser_compatibility shows that `overflow-wrap: break-word` is supported since Chrome 23, Edge 18, Firefox 49, Safari 6.1. It isn't supported in IE. (I am ignoring the non-standard name `word-wrap` here. I care only about the standard name.)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break#Browser_compatibility shows that `word-break: break-word` is supported since Chrome 1, Firefox 67, Safari 3. It isn't supported in IE and Edge.

Considering the browser support matrix, it looks like `overflow-wrap: break-word` works with all modern browsers.

What I want to know if you can imagine any type of text or HTML that would make `overflow-wrap: break-word` and `word-break: break-word` behave differently?

Comment: from the speficition : *For compatibility with legacy content, the word-break property also supports a deprecated break-word keyword. When specified, this has the same effect as word-break: normal and overflow-wrap: anywhere, regardless of the actual value of the overflow-wrap property.* (https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/#word-break-property) this can probably be a good starting point

Comment: This seems like a ppk question: https://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html . (Not saying he's answered it.)

Comment: @D_N What does "ppk" mean?

Comment: The initials of the guy who runs quirksmode. He does a ton of testing of edge case CSS things.

Answer (score 3):

To simplify it, `word-wrap` is an older version of [overflow-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) and has been replaced by [overflow-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) in the current CSS3 specification. This rule allows you to tell the browser is it allowed to break words when they are too long.

On the other hand, [word-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) allows you to tell the browser *how* to break the words.

As you've noted in your question, the `break-word` value for both of these rules will behave the same. See these definitions from the links I provided above:

`word-break: break-word`:

> To prevent overflow, normally unbreakable words may be broken at arbitrary points if there are no otherwise acceptable break points in the line.

`overflow-wrap: break-word`:

> The same as the anywhere value, with normally unbreakable words allowed to be broken at arbitrary points if there are no otherwise acceptable break points in the line, but soft wrap opportunities introduced by the word break are NOT considered when calculating min-content intrinsic sizes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `overflow-wrap: break-word` and `word-break: break-word` can behave differently. I've run into that, though I'm finding it hard to reproduce!

It helps to understand that at this point, `word-break: break-word` is really an alias for `overflow-wrap: anywhere`.

`word-break: break-word` is officially deprecated; see the [CSS Text Module Level 3 Working Draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/#valdef-word-break-break-word):

> For compatibility with legacy content, the `word-break` property also
>   supports a deprecated `break-word` keyword. When specified, this has the
>   same effect as `word-break: normal` and `overflow-wrap: anywhere`,
>   regardless of the actual value of the overflow-wrap property.

The thing to note here is that  `word-break: break-word` is an alias for `overflow-wrap: anywhere`, *NOT* an alias for `overflow-wrap: break-word`.

(`word-break: normal` is just the default value for `word-break`, so you can ignore it unless you're setting a different value for `word-break`.)

How do `overflow-wrap: anywhere` and `overflow-wrap: break-word` differ?

Well, here's a page from the wild, using `overflow-wrap: anywhere`:

[image]

And here's the same page, using `overflow-wrap: break-word`:

[image]

The only difference in the documentation between the two is that `overflow-wrap: anywhere` DOES "consider soft wrap opportunities introduced by the word break" when it is "calculating min-content intrinsic sizes", while `overflow-wrap: break-word` does NOT.

I guess widths might be more accurate in some cases if it is considering them?

Answer (score 1):

As written in [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break#values), `word-break: break-word` behaves as `word-break: normal` combined with `overflow-wrap: anywhere`, but overwrites actual `overflow-wrap` value.

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap#values) for `overflow-wrap` states that `anywhere` allows soft wraps (for example, on spaces), introduced by hard wraps, while `word-break` doesn't.

This means, that if the container has with depending on content size, `anywhere` will calculate width as if there are no overflowing words and then cut them to fit the container, while `word-break` will consider overflowing words as a reason to make the container as wide as possible.

In the example, the width is set as the longest word in the first sentence for `word-break: break-word` and `overflow-wrap: anywhere`, while `overflow-wrap: break-word` forces width to reach the limit, as there is a long word in the second sentence.

```css
.owbw {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.owaw {
  overflow-wrap: anywhere;
}

.wbbw {
  word-break: break-word;
}

div {
  width: min-content;
  max-width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<h3>overflow-wrap: break-word</h3>
<div>
This text has no reason to take the max width. <b  class="owbw">The word AVeryLongWordWithoutAnyPlacesToBreakIt might cause it in some cases.</b>
</div><br>

<h3>overflow-wrap: anywhere</h3>
<div>
This text has no reason to take the max width. <b  class="owaw">The word AVeryLongWordWithoutAnyPlacesToBreakIt might cause it in some cases.</b>
</div><br>

<h3>word-break: break-word</h3>
<div>
This text has no reason to take the max width. <b  class="wbbw">The word AVeryLongWordWithoutAnyPlacesToBreakIt might cause it in some cases.</b>
</div>
```