# Difference between `overflow-wrap: break-words` and `word-break: break-words`: why one work as intended and not the other one?

Tags: html, css

Is there a difference between `overflow-wrap: break-words` and `word-break: break-words`?

I read here and there that there is no difference, but my tests show that there is:

```html
<!-- actually break words -->
<table style="width: 100px; border: 1px solid red">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="word-break: break-word">
        hdsqdhsqydhsqgydqgsydgysqgydsqgydsgqydygsqgydsqgy
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<!-- do not break words -->
<table style="width: 100px; border: 1px solid red">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="overflow-wrap: break-word">
        hdsqdhsqydhsqgydqgsydgysqgydsqgydsgqydygsqgydsqgy
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

**Why does the first case work as intended and not the second?**

Comment: Because you are using tables - which don't have to adhere to your attempt to limit their width, unless you set `table-layout:fixed;`. Your second table simply stretches as wide as necessary without breaking the content

Comment: Duplicate of [overflow-wrap: break-word vs. word-break: break-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66724509/overflow-wrap-break-word-vs-word-break-break-word)

Comment: @CBroe Thank you! You can post your comment as an answer!

Comment: @GuyIncognito Not the same question!

Comment: I fail to see what the difference is

Comment: Not the same question, but the same underlying explanation, I think. `float` was what provided the _"something that sizes according the min content intrinsic size"_ context over there, here it is the table instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They behave like that in this specific situation here, because you have this wrapped in tables.

At table does not have to adhere to a width you try to specify, it is able to extend if the content requires it - unless `table-layout: fixed` is set.

The situation here is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/66828278/1427878,

> The difference lies in the way min content intrinsic sizes are calculated. Soft wrap opportunities introduced by the break are taken into account for word-break:break-word but not for overflow-wrap:break-word. So for an example of the difference between them, we need to choose something that sizes according the min content intrinsic size, such as a float:

Only here it is the table width calculation behavior that triggers it, instead of a float.