# Css: overflow-wrap: break-word; word-wrap: break-word; Differences

Tags: css, overflow, word-wrap

Is there any difference (**apart from browser support**) in terms of behavior between the following css properties?

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

and

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Perhaps **word-wrap** property has been just renamed to **overflow-wrap** in the current draft of the CSS3 Text specification?

I tried both on Chrome and seems to work in exact same way.

Am I correct or I'm missing something? Which one do I have to use?

Comment: http://caniuse.com might help you find out about support and what to use .

Comment: @Temani Afif: Hi thanks for passing by. I already seen and read the question you noticed as duplicate of this one. But please notice that I'm talking about **word-wrap: break-word;** not about **word-break: break-word;** contained into the answer you've noticed. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @G-Cyr Thank you for the comment, but the question specifies "a part the browser support", because I already know that aspect. What I'm asking in fact is if the two statements behave in different way somewhere because I'm not certain of that aspect.

Comment: Updated the duplicate list

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you but please would you please specify some more infos: I'm asking about **word-wrap:** statement you're kindly pointing out about the statement **word-break:**. As far as I know they are different css3 properties. Are they?

Comment: from the first duplicate you can read: *word-wrap property has been renamed overflow-wrap in the current draft of the CSS3 Text specification* ...  then in the second one : *word-wrap  is a legacy name for overflow-wrap. word-wrap is required for IE (11), Edge, and Opera Mini. Other major browsers now all support overflow-wrap (source).*

Comment: @TemaniAfif In other words the standard is **overflow-wrap** and the other perhaps is going to be deprecated in future so it is better to use **overflow-wrap** for css3 compliant browsers?

Comment: overflow-wrap is the standard name for its predecessor, the word-wrap property. word-wrap was originally a proprietary Internet Explorer-only feature that was eventually supported in all browsers despite not being a standard.

word-wrap accepts the same values as overflow-wrap and behaves the same way. According to the spec, browsers "must treat word-wrap as an alternate name for the overflow-wrap property, as if it were a shorthand of overflow-wrap". Also, all user agents are required to support word-wrap indefinitely, for legacy reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between the two. `overflow-wrap` is the same as `word-wrap`. As you pointed out, `word-wrap` was renamed to `overflow-wrap` as this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259916/difference-between-overflow-wrap-and-word-break) shows.