# how to show full large text option(without horizontal scrolling) by select2 ? reference in pic

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2, html-select

my select option showed like this
[image]

and my current code

```
<select class="rule-partner-select form-control select2" name="partner_name" id="partner_name_1">
    <option value="" disabled selected>SelectPartner</option>
</select>
```

I assign options in select dynamically by ajax.

select2 code here

```
 $('.select2').select2();
```

but I want to show like this by select2

[image]

Comment: this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259916/difference-between-overflow-wrap-and-word-break and this: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow-wrap/ and this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap and this: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved. Actually, I put a large word in the database !! "kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk...."
so the problem occurred.
when I put some white space (real sentence) like
"kkk kkkk kkkk kkkk kkkk kkkkk ",  it fulfills my requirement automatically by select2.

[image]

thanks. Please don't put large words!! :)