# Word break is not working in xhtml2pdf, when converted to pdf sentances are breaking mid word instead of end of word

Tags: xhtml2pdf

Am using [xhtml2pdf](https://xhtml2pdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) .
The issue am facing is the sentences are breaking into next line in the middle of words

Eg:- [image]

Tried using `word-wrap:break-word;-pdf-keep-with-next: true;overflow-wrap: break-word;` Not working

```html
<table class="card1 ">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="60%">DEDUCTIONS</th>
      <th>AMOUNT</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="word-wrap:break-word;-pdf-keep-with-next: true;"> Provident Fund Professional Tax Total Deductions Income Tax</td>
      <td class=" ">&#x20B9; 87,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class=" ">
        <p style="word-wrap:break-word;-pdf-keep-with-next: true;">Income Tax Provident Fund Professional Tax Total Deductions</p>
      </td>
      <td class=" ">&#x20B9; 32,090</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Professional Tax</td>
      <td>&#x20B9; 87,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td class=" ">Total Deductions</td>
      <td class=" ">&#x20B9; 1,29,328</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

give it a try with `overflow-wrap: break-word` instead of `word-wrap:break-word`

```
   <table class="card1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th width="60%">DEDUCTIONS</th>
          <th>AMOUNT</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="overflow-wrap: break-word; -pdf-keep-with-next: true;">Provident Fund Professional Tax Total Deductions Income Tax</td>
          <td class="">&#x20B9; 87,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="">
            <p style="overflow-wrap: break-word; -pdf-keep-with-next: true;">Income Tax Provident Fund Professional Tax Total Deductions</p>
          </td>
          <td class="">&#x20B9; 32,090</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Professional Tax</td>
          <td>&#x20B9; 87,000</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td class="">Total Deductions</td>
          <td class="">&#x20B9; 1,29,328</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
```

please go through the following

> **Overflow-wrap vs Word-break**
>
> Though overflow-wrap and word-break behave similarly there are
> differences between them. The overflow-wrap property breaks the word
> if it cannot be placed on the line without overflowing regardless of
> the language used. The word-break property is used for non-English
> languages and specifies wraps between letters of languages like
> Chinese, Japanese, and Korean.

also [word-wrap-and-overflow-wrap-break-word-and-break-all](https://webdesires.co.uk/knowledge-base/what-is-the-difference-between-word-wrap-and-overflow-wrap-break-word-and-break-all/#:%7E:text=The%20overflow%2Dwrap%20property%20breaks,Chinese%2C%20Japanese%2C%20and%20Korean.) and [difference-between-overflow-wrap-and-word-break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259916/difference-between-overflow-wrap-and-word-break) .

Comment: Not working, i think css support is less in xhtml. Any other suggestion