Tailwind break-words doesnt exist, how to solve?
I have the following case where I have a url in some div but the url breaks out of the div:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/hJOQaxaQxd
Ideally I could use word-break: break-word; but that doesnt exist. What do people do to solve this nicely?

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/word-break#break-words? This should work the same as word-break: break-word;, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259916/difference-between-overflow-wrap-and-word-break.

You can use break-all class to break the words. So, your updated anchor tag code would look like this:
<a href="https://someurl.com/HoH9cZVi8CMdvxVUNjvOzceUPVQcVZvvkf8ZbCOVOco" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" class="underline break-all" style="">https://someurl.com/HoH9cZVi8CMdvxVUNjvOzceUPVQcVZvvkf8ZbCOVOco</a>

Additionally, you can reference all break options here: Tailwind Break

break-all doesnt look as good as if i could use break-word. Like a url i want to go to the next line so it doesnt start with stay htt... (nextline is the rest of the url)
